# Display one item from String Array and excluding one item using Math.Random

Tags: java, arrays, random, linked-list

How can I display one item from an Array list using Math.Random whilst excluding items that are found to be equal to? This code searchs through a linked list array to find if it matches any items from the string array, if it does it will print one random element from the string array that is not already within the linked list?

```
public static void pagesYouMayLike(LinkedList[] likes, int index, String [] likeArray){

  for(int i=0; i<likes[index].size(); i++){

     for(int j=0; j<5; j++ ){

        if(likes[index].listIterator(i).next().equals(likeArray[j])){

           int idx = new Random().nextInt(likeArray.length);

           System.out.println(likeArray[idx]);

        }//if
     }//for
   }//for
 }//pages you may like
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
 if(likes[index].listIterator(i).next().equals(likeArray[j])){

       int idx = new Random().nextInt(likeArray.length);

       for(int i =0; i< likes.size(); i++){ //traverse through the linked list array
             if(likeArray[idx] != likes[i]){  // and check to see if this is a unique string.
                 System.out.println(likeArray[idx]);
                 break;
             }else{
                 idx = new Random().nextInt(likeArray.length); //pick another random string
             }
       }

    }//if
```

This compares the chosen random string to the linked list array to see if it is unique. If it is it should print it out and break out of the loop. You might need to use an iterator in the for loop instead but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: any ideas on how to make sure a number is generated once only?

Comment: @user3605306 I guess you could keep track of the numbers generated and put them into an array and then compare if the new number generated is the same as the one in the array, if same then generate a new number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about iterators, it would be a lot easier to use a for-each loop:

```
for(String s : likes) {
    if (Arrays.asList(likeArray).contains(s)) {
        int index = (new Random()).nextInt(likeArray.length);
        System.out.println(likeArray[index]);
    }
}
```

If you want to display only a single random value, just put a break in the loop after the random value is found.